# Laravel Auth RedirectTo will be ignored

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

i use the default LoginController from Laravel 5.4 Auth. I just modified the `redirectTo` property to /

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Now i logged in as a user. After login the redirect to / works fine.
So now i goto `/login` again and now the `trait RedirectsUsers` redirect's me to `/home`.

I think the problem is in the trait on this line:

```
return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
```

But i didn't understand why. In the `LoginController` the `redirectTo` will be set to /.

I don't want to override the `RedirectsUsers` trait in the vendor directory.

How i can fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When user is logging in, redirection is done by using the

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

---

When user is already logged in and visits the `/login` page, redirection (to `/home`) is defined in
this middleware

`app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` [source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8f99719dfe74b798dadf679c587d68727a2d4797/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21)

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

**guest** middleware is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php` [source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8f99719dfe74b798dadf679c587d68727a2d4797/app/Http/Kernel.php#L58)

Edited answer to respond to the comment

**guest** middleware is added to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` [source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8f99719dfe74b798dadf679c587d68727a2d4797/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php#L37)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats all fine. But i didn't understand why the redirectTo is /home when the user is logged in, and / (whats correct) when it's a guest user

Comment: Redirection **when user is logging in** is done in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`, and redirection **after user is already logged in** is done in `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

Comment: thank you very much. didn't recognized it. exactly what i looking for.

Comment: You are welcome! Updated the answer again, added more details